# How do I change the input layer for a pretrained GAN?

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I downloaded several pre-trained GANs at this link https://github.com/lukemelas/pytorch-pretrained-gans. However, they don't seem to have the flexibility to create the kinds of images I want or match arbitrary target images. I think I can get greater flexibility by inputting codes to one of the larger fully connected layers, rather than the initial, smaller fully connected layer. Does anyone know how to skip the first couple layers of a pretrained gan and input codes directly to one of the deeper layers?

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot change the input layer of a pretrained model. If you change any layer, all subsequent layers (weights) get invalidated and need to be retrained.

Comment: You can a stylegan sort of model that allows you to add input vectors at intermediate layers of supervision. Although what you are asking for requires a much detailed level of understanding and code modification. Can you share a code example?